# Premake: Build Command with Multiple Inputs and Multiple Outputs

Tags: premake

**Summary question**: How do you write a Premake command that can take multiple inputs and generate multiple outputs?

I am trying to use a Premake [custom build command](https://premake.github.io/docs/Custom-Build-Commands) for a program which generates code that takes multiple inputs and creates multiple outputs. However, I can't figure out the Premake to take multiple inputs.

The Protocol Buffer compiler `protoc` is one such program that operates in this way that I will use for demonstration. This script works for taking all of the `.proto` files and compiling them individually:

```lua
workspace "CustomBuildCommandTesting"
    configurations { "Debug", "Release" }
    location "build"

project "custom-buildcommand-test"
    kind "ConsoleApp"
    language "C++"
    targetdir "build/%{cfg.buildcfg}/bin"

    files { "src/**.cpp", "src/**.proto" }
    includedirs { "%{cfg.objdir}/generated" }

    -- Using protoc for demo, but the question applies to anything with multiple inputs
    filter 'files:**.proto'
        buildcommands {
            'mkdir -p "%{cfg.objdir}/generated"',
            'protoc --proto_path=../src --cpp_out="%{cfg.objdir}/generated" "%{file.relpath}"',
        }

        buildoutputs {
            '%{cfg.objdir}/generated/%{file.basename}.pb.h',
            '%{cfg.objdir}/generated/%{file.basename}.pb.cc',
        }
```

This creates rules in Make that look like this (cleaned a bit for clarity):

```
obj/Debug/generated/foo.pb.h: ../src/foo.proto
    mkdir -p "obj/Release/generated"
    protoc --proto_path=../src --cpp_out="obj/Release/generated" "../src/foo.proto"

obj/Debug/generated/bar.pb.h: ../src/bar.proto
    mkdir -p "obj/Debug/generated"
    protoc --proto_path=../src --cpp_out="obj/Debug/generated" "../src/bar.proto"
```

As an aside, there is no mention of the `.pb.cc` files that get generated anywhere, which is not ideal. It seems like that should get picked up from `buildoutputs`, but I must be missing how to make that happen.

The real problem here is this isn't the way you're supposed to use `protoc`. For `protoc`, you want to use all of the inputs to generate all of the outputs in one pass. A more-correct rule in Make would look like this:

```
obj/Debug/generated/bar.pb.h  \
obj/Debug/generated/bar.pb.cc \
obj/Debug/generated/foo.pb.h  \
obj/Debug/generated/foo.pb.cc \
        :                     \
        ../src/bar.proto      \
        ../src/foo.proto
    mkdir -p "obj/Debug/generated"
    protoc --proto_path=../src --cpp_out="obj/Debug/generated" $^
```

**The core question**: How do you write a Premake command that can take multiple inputs and generate multiple outputs?

---

For completeness, here's the full demo source tree.

```
.
├── premake5.lua
└── src
    ├── bar.proto
    ├── foo.proto
    └── main.cpp
```

`src/foo.proto`:

```
syntax = "proto3";

message Foo {
    uint64 value = 1;
}
```

`src/bar.proto`:

```
syntax = "proto3";

import "foo.proto";

message Bar {
    Foo foo = 1;
}
```

`src/main.cpp`:

```cpp
#include "bar.pb.h"

int main()
{
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*As of 2023-11-15*, this seems to be something Premake does not really do elegantly, but I opened [issue 2160](https://github.com/premake/premake-core/issues/2160) so this might change in the future. For now, here's a workaround.

The workaround here is to build up the list of inputs and outputs manually, then pass them to `buildinputs` and `buildoutputs` by hand. The trick when setting the `filter` is to just pick one of the `.proto` input files; it does not matter which one, since they're all in `buildinputs` anyway.

```lua
workspace "CustomBuildCommandTesting"
    configurations { "Debug", "Release" }
    location "build"

project "custom-buildcommand-test"
    kind "ConsoleApp"
    language "C++"
    targetdir "build/%{cfg.buildcfg}/bin"

    files { "src/**.cpp", "src/**.proto", "%{cfg.objdir}/generated/**.cc" }
    includedirs { "%{cfg.objdir}/generated" }
    links { "protobuf" }

    proto_files = os.matchfiles("src/**.proto")
    proto_files_arg = ''
    for _, fname in ipairs(proto_files) do
        realpath, err = os.realpath(fname)
        if err ~= nil then
            -- TODO: error handling
            printf("Error getting realpath of %s: %s", fname, err)
        end

        proto_files_arg = proto_files_arg..' "'..realpath..'"'
    end
    src_realpath, err = os.realpath('src')
    if err ~= nil then
        -- TODO: error handling
        printf("Error getting realpath of %s: %s", 'src', err)
    end

    -- collect outputs, too
    outputs = {}
    for idx, fname in ipairs(proto_files) do
        -- remove the "src/" and ".proto". This numbers seem 1 larger than they should be because Lua is 1-indexed
        basename = fname:sub(5, -7)
        outputs[(idx-1) * 2 + 1] = '%{cfg.objdir}/generated/'..basename..'.pb.h'
        outputs[(idx-1) * 2 + 2] = '%{cfg.objdir}/generated/'..basename..'.pb.cc'
    end

    -- just pick _a_ proto file -- it doesn't matter which
    filter('files:'..proto_files[1])
        buildinputs(proto_files)
        buildoutputs(outputs)

        buildcommands {
            'mkdir -p "%{cfg.objdir}/generated"',
            'protoc --proto_path="'..src_realpath..'" --cpp_out="%{cfg.objdir}/generated"'..proto_files_arg,
        }

        compilebuildoutputs "on"
    filter{}
```

This all works. In Make, there is a `foo.pb.h` rule that looks like this:

```
obj/Debug/generated/foo.pb.h: ../src/foo.proto ../src/foo.proto ../src/bar.proto
    mkdir -p "obj/Debug/generated"
    protoc --proto_path="../src" --cpp_out="obj/Debug/generated" "../src/foo.proto" "../src/bar.proto"
```

Which is linked to the other generated files by a rule without a recipe:

```
obj/Debug/generated/foo.pb.cc obj/Debug/generated/bar.pb.h obj/Debug/generated/bar.pb.cc: obj/Debug/generated/foo.pb.h
```

If a non-generated file needs `bar.pb.h` (as `main.cpp` does here), the Makefile kind-of knows that it needs `foo.pb.h` to get it and picks it up properly as a side-effect. The "correct" solution is [grouped targets](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Multiple-Targets.html#Multiple-Targets), but this one works Good Enough.

Comment: `outputs[(idx-1) * 2 + 1] = filename .. "pb.h"` -> `table.insert(outputs, filename .. "pb.h")`.